# How can I adjust the written text in text type input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, padding

I am creating an opening search box, that you click then it opens, but i have a problem with the text, this is how it works :

```css
.search {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.search-box input {
  background: #F5B7B1;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
}

.search-box label {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 12px
}

.search-box label i {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

#check:checked ~ .search-box input{
  max-width: 350px;
}

#check{
  display: none;
}

.search-box input::placeholder{
color: #E5E7E9;
padding-left: 20px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- Fontawesome CDN Link -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <div class="search">
    <input id="check" type="checkbox" />
    <div class="search-box">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type here..." />
      <label for="check">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

It looks good ,but still there a problem which is that the text that the user write will be at the very left, i don't want it like that, i want it to be like the placeholder, with padding: 20px
So i tried to edit the original input :

```css
    .search {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }

    .search-box input {
      background: #F5B7B1;
      color: white;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      height: 40px;
      width: 350px;
      max-width: 0px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
      padding-left: 20px
    }

    .search-box label {
      position: absolute;
      height: 30px;
      width: 40px;
      background-color: #E74C3C;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 12px
    }

    .search-box label i {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: white;
    }

    #check:checked ~ .search-box input{
      max-width: 350px;
    }

    #check{
      display: none;
    }

    .search-box input::placeholder{
    color: #E5E7E9;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- Fontawesome CDN Link -->
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
        />
      </head>
      <div class="search">
        <input id="check" type="checkbox" />
        <div class="search-box">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Type here..." />
          <label for="check">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </html>
```

There is another problem here which is the input is out of the area that it should be in, how can I solve this, please!!

Comment: The `padding-left: 20px` in `.search-box input` works as expected in the 2nd snippet (Chrome 92).

Comment: What do you mean by _the input is out of the area that it should be in_?

Comment: this [article](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/26/expanding-search-bar-deconstructed/) will help you.

Comment: @RobMoll I mean that the pink input on the left is very far from the box that contains the icon, I want the text that the user writes to be a little far from the edge of the input, not at the very left like in the 2nd snippet, do you have a solution of that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `marging-left` css property on `.search-box label` to place the search button correctly.

Use a negative margin of `-20px` to close the gap completely, or `-18px` to let the `<input>` background show through a little bit as seen in your first example.

```css
.search {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.search-box input {
  background: #F5B7B1;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.search-box label {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 12px;
  margin-left: -18px;
}

.search-box label i {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

#check:checked ~ .search-box input {
  max-width: 350px;
  padding-right: 38px;
}

#check{
  display: none;
}

.search-box input::placeholder{
  color: #E5E7E9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<!-- Fontawesome CDN Link -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
/>
  </head>
  <div class="search">
<input id="check" type="checkbox" />
<div class="search-box">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type here..." />
  <label for="check">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  </label>
</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

A right padding of `38px` – at least `18px` to offset the negative margin + optional `20px` to match the left padding for symmetry – should be applied to `.search-box input` to not let longer search texts go below the search button.

Thanks to @Tim for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: Although a good answer, this will cause the end of an input text to be hidden under the search icon if the input text is very long.  Please see my answer below which also solves that issue.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your comment. Yes, a right padding should be added but will work with the margin too.

Comment: @YacineBenhenni Please also add a right padding of `38px` to `#check:checked ~ .search-box input` to avoid longer search texts scrolling under the search button. Check my update for details.

Answer (score 1):

Applying `right: -18px;` to `.search-box label` and `padding-right: 40px;` to `#check:checked ~ .search-box input` will get you what you want:

```css
.search {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }

    .search-box input {
      background: #F5B7B1;
      color: white;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      height: 40px;
      width: 350px;
      max-width: 0px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s 0s ease;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .search-box label {
      position: absolute;
      height: 30px;
      width: 40px;
      background-color: #E74C3C;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 12px;
      right: -18px;
    }

    .search-box label i {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: white;
    }

    #check:checked ~ .search-box input{
      max-width: 350px;
      padding-right: 40px;
    }

    #check{
      display: none;
    }

    .search-box input::placeholder{
    color: #E5E7E9;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- Fontawesome CDN Link -->
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
        />
      </head>
      <div class="search">
        <input id="check" type="checkbox" />
        <div class="search-box">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Type here..." />
          <label for="check">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Good observation +1